# Dynamic average based on data range

Tags: excel, vba

I have a dataset (that is a sheet in my xlsm) with two columns: the first one is the date and the second one is USD value at the day. Besides that there is two cells one for the "Data Start" and another one for "Data End" I want to excel to take the AVERAGE value of USD in the DATA START/DATA END interval. How can I do that? I want a dynamic average.

For instance, I put 04/01/2021 on DATA START and 21/06/2021 on DATA END. And I want the average to be calculated between this two cells.

Can I do this with VBA? Will it be easier?

Comment: `AVERAGEIFS()` could likely do that.  No need for VBA

Comment: Thank you! It worked. So kind of you. I had a problem with Standard Deviation but I've made it.